# Check if value is multiple of 10

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a value is a multiple of a certain number, for example, multiples of 10, but I also want to be able to change it to whatever I want.

```
if (directWinner == 10){

}
```

Comment: This does have absolutely nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Amazing. Staggering. http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: -1 all the answers, not enough jQuery.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'd use the modulus operator for that :

```
if (directWinner % 10 === 0){
    directWinner = 20;
}
```

Added a small dose of jQuery for no good reason at all ?

```
$.modu = function(check, against) {
    return check % against === 0;
}

if ( $.modu(directWinner, 10) ) {
    directWinner = 20;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `directWinner % 10 === 0`?

Comment: is it two equal signs or 3?

Comment: When for checking for zero, usually three. @Bergi - changed it within seconds, was typing a bit too fast.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) for that:

```
var certainNumber = 10;
if (directWinner % certainNumber === 0) {
    // directWinner is a multiple of certainNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator (assuming positive integers) :

```
if (directWinner % 10 === 0) {
    ...
}
```